# ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list. Is this a valid way to create a neural network in PyTorch?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I have been trying to implelemnt SRGAN for a project, however when i try to create a optimizer for my generator I run into error:

```
ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list.
```

I have checked my parameters and they are indeed an empty list, the issue is that I don't know how to access those parameters, when I was implementing other network architectures I have met no such problem.

I think that due to my lack of experience with the framework i might have messed up when creating generator class so I have included code snippet below.

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
    super(Generator, self).__init__()
    self.in_channels = in_channels
    self.out_channels = out_channels

  @staticmethod
  def block(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1):
    return nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, padding=padding, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
        nn.PReLU()
    )
  
  @staticmethod
  def input_block(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=9, padding=4):
    return nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, padding=padding, bias=False),
        nn.PReLU()
    )

  @staticmethod
  def output_block(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1):
    return nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, padding=padding, bias=False),
        nn.PixelShuffle(2),
        nn.PReLU()
    )

  def forward(self, x):
    block_in = self.input_block(self.in_channels, self.out_channels)(x)
    block1 = T.add(self.block(self.out_channels, self.out_channels)(block_in), block_in)
    block2 = T.add(self.block(self.out_channels, self.out_channels)(block1), block1)
    block3 = T.add(self.block(self.out_channels, self.out_channels)(block2), block2)
    block4 = T.add(self.block(self.out_channels, self.out_channels)(block3), block3)
    block_bridge = T.add(block4, block_in)
    block5 = self.output_block(self.out_channels, self.out_channels * 4)(block_bridge)
    block6 = self.output_block(self.out_channels, self.out_channels * 4)(block5)
    _output = nn.Conv2d(self.out_channels, self.in_channels, 9, padding=4, bias=False)(block6)
    return _output
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the layers that you plan on using in `__init__` like this:

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
    super(Generator, self).__init__()
    self.in_channels = in_channels
    self.out_channels = out_channels
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=9, padding=4, bias=False)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False)
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels * 4, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False)
    self.prelu = nn.PReLU()
    self.batchnorm = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
    self.pixshuff = nn.PixelShuffle(2)
    self.output = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, in_channels, kernel_size=9, padding=4, bias=False) 


  def block(self):
    return nn.Sequential(
        self.conv2,
        self.batchnorm,
        self.prelu,
    )
  
  def input_block(self):
    return nn.Sequential(
        self.conv1,
        self.prelu,
    )

  def output_block(self):
    return nn.Sequential(
        self.conv3,
        self.pixshuff,
        self.prelu
    )

  def forward(self, x):
    block_in = self.input_block()(x)
    block1 = T.add(self.block()(block_in), block_in)
    block2 = T.add(self.block()(block1), block1)
    block3 = T.add(self.block()(block2), block2)
    block4 = T.add(self.block()(block3), block3)
    block_bridge = T.add(block4, block_in)
    block5 = self.output_block()(block_bridge)
    block6 = self.output_block()(block5)
    output = self.output(block6)
    return output
```

Comment: Good job; don't forget to come back after 48 hours to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).